# ajax doesn't work on a user's on IE9

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9

I have built an ajax-based chat room. It all works fine except for one user who doesn't see any of the ajax-generated content. He's using IE9.

Enable native XMLHTTP support is checked.

Where else should he look in his settings?

Comment: Any other IE users you can confirm it works for? It might be an IE problem if you don't check for activex ajax methods.

Comment: it works on my IE9 with no problem and loads of others

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be [caching the ajax results](http://dougwilsonsa.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/disabling-ie9-ajax-response-caching-asp-net-mvc-3-jquery/). If you're using MVC you can simply change the cache-control meta with via this:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public class CacheTestController : Controller
```

Comment: the ajax string always has a random value parameter in it to avoid caching. Plus if it were a cache issue then the user would see the content on first visiting the page but not the updates. As it is he sees no content at all.

Answer (score 0):

I got the user to install Chrome and try there and that didn't help. So it must have been their Internet connection or firewall settings. Turns out it was the latter as, when they lowered the safety a bit, it all worked.